# Rendering issues using LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, render, lwjgl

[image]

In the picture I have rendered my terrain with a few basic models (tree + shrub), but I had been noticing some glitching that was occuring with the models. Knowing this, I rendered a flat plane of "water" onto my world and it showed what I had thought. I am still unsure of what is wrong here, any insight would be helpful!

Note:
I am using LWJGL
The plane of "water" is flat, and the area that it is in is concave, so no part of it sticks above the "water"

Comment: anyone have an answer? or atleast an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: This is the result of having too small of a zNear value when calculating projection method. If you dont know what that is, search up how to create a projection matrix 3d and it will explain :) Finally solved it and can get moving with my game, hope this can help others!